# Importing firebase from node_modules not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a folder in htdocs directory named firestore, and using cmd to install npm firebase
in firestore directory. It generates package.json, package-lock.json and node_modules. I want to link to firebase but it is not working. I take away the firebaseconfig key for privacy reasons and yes, I did create a firestore database project in firebase. When I use **import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-app.js";** and **import {
getFirestore,
collection,
getDocs,
onSnapshot,
addDoc,
deleteDoc,
doc,
getDoc,
updateDoc,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-firestore.js";** , it is working fine. However I want to use from firebase/app instead of url.

Code that links to firebase:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "node_modules/firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from "node_modules/firebase/firestore";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore();


export const saveTask = (title, description) =>
  addDoc(collection(db, "tasks"), { title, description });

export const onGetTasks = (callback) =>
  onSnapshot(collection(db, "tasks"), callback);


export const deleteTask = (id) => deleteDoc(doc(db, "tasks", id));

export const getTask = (id) => getDoc(doc(db, "tasks", id));

export const updateTask = (id, newFields) =>
  updateDoc(doc(db, "tasks", id), newFields);

export const getTasks = () => getDocs(collection(db, "tasks"));
```

firestore directory:
[image]

and inside node_modules: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it like this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
// ...
```

or like so if you use common js:

```js
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase/app');
const { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } = require('firebase/firestore');
// ...
```

Just remove "node_modules/" from the import statement

[See the package DOCs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `app` to `getFirestore` function.
Like this:

```
 export const db = getFirestore(app);
```